# Select based on count of IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of customers I got through a `select`, `case` and `group by` statement. I get the correct values but my issue is the following:

My table

```
 ID Name Contract
 1  ABC  Contract
 2  DEF  No Contract
 2  DEF  Contract
 3  GHI  No Contract
```

Some Customers can be part in contract and part not like customer `2`.
I need a select from this that will give me:

```
 ID Name Contract
 1  ABC  Contract
 2  DEF  Mixed
 3  GHI  No Contract
```

If a customer `id` only appears once I need `Contract` as is, otherwise I want the customer **only once** with the word `Mixed` for `Contract`

This is what I have so far:

```
with T as(
  select [DEBTORID]
  , [DEBTOR]
  , case 
    when [CONTRACTTYPE]='KAM' then 'Contract' 
    when [CONTRACTTYPE]='SME' then 'Contract' 
    when [CONTRACTTYPE]='CCS' then 'Contract' 
    else 'Deemed' 
    end as 'Contract'
  FROM [FinancialReporting].[dbo].[LiveGasMeters]
  group by [DEBTORID],[DEBTOR],[CONTRACTTYPE]
  )
  select T.[DEBTORID]
  , T.DEBTOR
  , T.[Contract]
  from T
  group by [DEBTORID],DEBTOR,[Contract]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `group by id, name` to aggregate and use a `CASE` expression:

```
select id, name,
  case count(distinct contract)
    when 1 then max(contract)
    else 'Mixed'
  end Contract
from tablename
group by id, name
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=63dcba0587c2ba6833eb10117617316d).
Results:

```
> id | name | Contract   
> -: | :--- | :----------
>  1 | ABC  | Contract   
>  2 | DEF  | Mixed      
>  3 | GHI  | No Contract
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write this as:

```
select id, name,
       (case when min(contract) = max(contract) then min(contract)
             else 'Mixed'
        end) as contract
from t
group by id, name;
```